# "multiple definition of `main'" error

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 nodes/files(one node for each file) in my package. It's like in talker and listener tutorial. However, after adding a new one (second node/file), I received an error of "multiple definition of `main'". I've check all the braces, they are well-placed.

What could be the possible culprits?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12433/%22multiple-definition-of-%60main%27%22-error/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-22**:
I've just updated the question.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-22**:
Could you be more clear? You added a second what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just forgot to change the node name in the "rosbuild_add_executable" parameter in the CMakeList.txt. I only added the different name for both of them, but not the node name.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3